# Python CFFI: Build single module from multiple source files

Tags: python, python-3.x, pypy, python-cffi, cffi

My aim is to build a single module/extension from multiple C source files. What is the best practice to achieve this?

**What I tried:**

I know that the`ffi.set_source` function has the optional `sources` and `include_dir` kwargs and that there should be a possibility to use these kwargs to build a single shared object from multiple source files. Unfortunately I cannot find anything regarding these kwargs in the API reference of the [CFFI Documentation](https://cffi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). So I can't figure out the details. Is there any document which explains how to properly use these kwargs?

**I currently use:**

```py
SOURCES = ('file_1.c', 'file_2.c')
SRC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), '../src')

ffi_builder = FFI()
ffi_builder.set_source(
    'module_name._module_name',
    ''.join(f'#include "{source}"\n' for source in SOURCES),
    include_dirs=[SRC_ROOT],
)

...
```

Although this actually works, it seems a bit hacky to me. Is it possible to use `sources` kwarg instead of the 2nd positional arg `source`? This would allow me to get rid of the hacky `''.join(f'#include "{source}"\n' for source in SOURCES)` part.

If there is even a simpler approach, I would also be interested!

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation for `set_source`](https://cffi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cdef.html#ffibuilder-set-source-preparing-out-of-line-modules) states

> The keywords arguments to `set_source()` control how the C compiler will be called. They are passed directly to `distutils` or `setuptools` and include at least `sources`, `include_dirs`, `define_macros`, `undef_macros`, `libraries`, `library_dirs`, `extra_objects`, `extra_compile_args` and `extra_link_args`. You typically need at least `libraries=['foo']` in order to link with `libfoo.so` or `libfoo.so.X.Y`, or `foo.dll` on Windows. **The `sources` is a list of extra .c files compiled and linked together (the file `module_name.c` shown above is always generated and automatically added as the first argument to `sources`**). See the distutils documentations for more information about the other arguments.

So yes, you can use `sources` as a kwarg

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer! What exactly do I have to pass to `sources`? The documentation does not really help:

```bash
Help on function set_source in cffi.FFI:

$ pydoc cffi.FFI.set_source

cffi.FFI.set_source = set_source(self, module_name, source, source_extension='.c', **kwds)
(END)
```

And what do I have to pass to the 2nd required arugments `source` in this case?

Comment: See the bold text above: sources is a list of c files